# Spring security with hibernate and mysql login

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

my project is based on Spring and Hibernate and now I have to implement authentication and profiling both from database and LDAP.
Given that I am new in spring I thought to start with implementation of authentication from database and then I'll think to profile and LDAP.
I followed this guide [spring security annotation](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/) but when I call my web page it works like before, no authentication is called.
These are my configuration classes:

SpringSecurityInitializer

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

    public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    }
```

SpringMvcInitializer

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
```

public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}   
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**")
        .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").permitAll();//.failureUrl("/login?error")
        //.usernameParameter("username")
        //.passwordParameter("password")
        //.and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        //.and().csrf()
        //.and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

}
```

AppConfig

```
    @EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.*" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class, SpringMvcInitializer.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.repository")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
//  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";  

    /**
     * This and the next methods are used to avoid exception while jackson mapping the entity, so fields are setted with null value
     * unless use Hibernate.initialize
     * @return
     */
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter(){
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //Registering Hibernate4Module to support lazy objects
        mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());

        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return messageConverter;

    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        //Here we add our custom-configured HttpMessageConverter
        converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
//      properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
        properties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans",true);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        ds.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        ds.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        ds.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver TemplateResolver(){
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
        /*ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return resolver;*/
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(TemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }


    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[]{"*", "js/*", "template/*"});
        return resolver;
    }

    /**
     * Register multipartResolver for file upload
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return resolver;    
    }

    /**
     * Allow use of bootstrap
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

    /**
     * Allow use of JPA
     */
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.
        getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;

    }
}
```

MyUserDetailsServices

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.domain.UserRole;
import com.services.dbservices.tables.UserServices;

@Service("userDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserServices userServices;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        com.domain.User user = userServices.findById(username);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRole());

        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);

    }

    // Converts com.users.model.User user to
    // org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
    private User buildUserForAuthentication(com.domain.User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {

        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        // Build user's authorities
        for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getUserRoleKeys().getRole()));
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

        return Result;
    }

}
```

MainController

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class MainControllerImpl implements MainController{

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String mainPage(){
        return "index";
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(){
        return "login";
    }
}
```

How you can see, I am only using annotations without any xml configuration file.
Where is the problem? If someone has a good guide for spring security with hibernate , Ldap with annotation I thank him. 
at the moment, only to for testing, login.html

```
<div class="login-box-body">
            <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>
            <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                <div th:if="${param.error}">
                    <script>
                        notifyMessage("Invalid username and password!", 'error');
                    </script>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${param.logout}">
                    <script>
                        notifyMessage("You have been logged out!", 'error');
                    </script>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input id="username" name="username" type="text"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="Username"> <span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="password"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="Password"> <span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="checkbox icheck">
                            <label> <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <button id="signinButton" type="submit"
                            class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
            </form>

            <div class="social-auth-links text-center">
                <p>- OR -</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook btn-flat"><i
                    class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in using Facebook</a> <a href="#"
                    class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google btn-flat"><i
                    class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> Sign in using Google+</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.social-auth-links -->

            <a href="#">I forgot my password</a><br> <a href="register.html"
                class="text-center">Register a new membership</a>

        </div>
```

Comment: What is the relationship with Hibernate? It is merely used to fetch the `User` entity using `userServices.findById(username)` where it already succeeds.

Comment: I mean with database login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add in AppConfig

```
@Bean
public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect() {
    SpringSecurityDialect dialect = new SpringSecurityDialect();
    return dialect;
}
```

and in SecurityConfig

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
           //Spring Security ignores request to static resources such as CSS or JS files.
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/static/**");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Spring-security but in this line :

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
    .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").and().formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
```

you are saying that only autentificated pereson with ROLE "ROLE_ADMIN" can make request for "/admin/**".
But your controller only have routes for "/" and "/welcome" 
So you never ask for anything inside "/admin/"

If you want to try if your spring-security configuration works, change your controller to something like:

```
@Controller
```

public class MainControllerImpl {

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/admin/welcome" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String singleUpload(){
    return "index";
}
```

}